# Load Jupyter notebook from outside pre-set startup directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Say my startup directory for Jupyter is `/User/All/Directory/`, how can I load a notebook from `/User/All/` in Jupyter without changing the startup directory?

*I'm working with a Mac, in case that's relevant.*

Comment: Are you using JupyterLab?

Comment: Negative @MikeMüller, using the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Check all path of anaconda is proper or not, then open terminal, go on that path where you want to open jupyter notebook and type "jupyter notebook" and press enter, jupyter notebook will open in default browser.

Comment: Doesn't work – takes me to the preset root directory.